# What type of sensors are these?

Tags: sensor, imageprocessing

[image]

I saw this sensors in an YouTube video where these things were glued to Glenn Maxwell's dress and his whole movement was monitored for the making of a cricket game.

Comment: If I recall correctly, those aren't sensors, they're beacons for external sensors to track.

Comment: they are just "dots" ... video camera and motion recognition software translate the dots to this  http://www.gotoandplay.it/_articles/2007/04/skeletal_animation/ragdoll0.jpg  .... other software uses the resulting data  to animate virtual actors

Comment: Typically used for 3D animation for movies and video games. They're not sensors but rather "joints" that a computer can recognize and detect so that a model is able to mimic the movement. They then put the locations into some type of stick figure model and then whatever want over that stick figure model (i.e. a monster or some supernatural being). Saves a lot of money and time to animate 3D objects this way as opposed to frame by frame movements.

Comment: They are reflective IR balls that IR cameras can easily see, they have a few cameras and the position of each ball can be triangulated to a few mm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think those are sensors. I think those balls, against a black background, are a constellation that can be dealt with efficiently using computer vision techniques from normal camera output. Algorithms that know something about how they are distributed on a moving body can infer the movement of that body through space mapped onto a 3-D model with hinges and joints. The technology as a whole is called "motion capture" I believe.

Maybe they are also highly reflective to IR or something, but I seriously doubt they are "active" in any way.

Comment: Here's a link for more reading: https://www.engadget.com/2014/07/14/motion-capture-explainer/